# in rails warning: already initialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psych

```
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/psych.so: warning:       already initialized constant ANY
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant UTF8
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant UTF16LE
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant UTF16BE
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant ANY
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb:15: warning: already initialized constant UTF8
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb:18: warning: already initialized constant UTF16LE
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb:21: warning: already initialized constant UTF16BE
```

i got this error when i strated my rails server for the first time after creating a new rails project. could anyone help me out of this

Comment: What gems are you using?

Comment: gem 'rails', '3.2.7'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the solution described [on this gist](https://gist.github.com/1266144) will help:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
gem uninstall psych
gem install psych
```

Answer (score 11):

The fix for me was simply to do `gem uninstall psych`.

Comment: i want to use psych for other application so i cant uninstall it. This  works fine.. rvm use 1.9.3
             gem uninstall psych
             gem install psych

Comment: This was the solution in my case too. I think the Ruby SDK I was using in RubyMine had possibly ended up with one copy, while Rails was loading another copy. Or something. Either way, uninstalling psych from the command line cheered it up.